# How to create this kind "slide out view controller"?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I think that the "slide out"-functionality of the iOS mail app or the music player app is pretty neat. Can you tell me whether this is a builtin feature and how to configure segues/view controllers to achieve this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/MarioIannotta/PullUpController) out, Hope it will help!

Comment: Here you can see implementation of this screen by Ray Wenderlich https://www.raywenderlich.com/178798/recreating-the-apple-music-now-playing-transition

Comment: Thanks! Both of your comments are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

https://github.com/rashed008/swiftBottomSheet

[Bottom Sheet for iOS](https://github.com/rashed008/swiftBottomSheet)
Just change the tint color of that handle view and other customization as per your requirement.

Image -

[image: Image No. 1]

[image: Image No. 2]